# How do I operate on strings in an array?

Tags: python

I'm trying to work a previously defined function on a sentence, and I've gotten as far as separating into word strings, but I can't figure out how to make a loop of it. Please help. Code is below.

```
def pig_latin_sentence(sentence):
    ''' Converts a string of words separated by spaces to Pig Latin'''
    words=sentence.split(" ")
    for
        pig_latin(word)
        sentence2=sentence2+word
return sentence2
```

Comment: `for word in words`?

Comment: It doesn't look like you ran into a specific issue so much as that you ran out of steam while coding. Keep going.

Comment: What have you tried? What is the expected result? You seem to know you need a for loop, so how do you loop over *any* list?

Comment: or, without a loop: `sentence2 = [pig_latin(word) for word in sentence.split(" ")]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The loop should maybe look like this if the pig_latin function adds spaces appropriately::

```
def pig_latin_sentence(sentence):
    ''' Converts a string of words separated by spaces to Pig Latin'''
    words=sentence.split(" ")
    for word in words:
        pig_latin(word)
        sentence2=sentence2+word
return sentence2
```

But if not, then maybe something like this using join and avoiding the for loop with the map function would be better:

```
def pig_latin_sentence(sentence):
    ''' Converts a string of words separated by spaces to Pig Latin'''
    return ' '.join( map( pig_latin, sentence.split() ) )
```